# Convert jQuery object to javascript inside Ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

I have an Ajax function written in Javascript to load posts while scrolling. The grid is a Masonry style (using Colcade JS).

The issue is that I can't find the way to convert this jQuery line of code to Javascript. I would like to wrap the Ajax `data` into an objet and use it to parse the HTML.

```
const posts = $(data);
```

The JS:

```
const grid = document.querySelector(".js-grid");

    if (grid) {
        
        // Colcade JS
        var colc = new Colcade(grid, {
            columns: '.js-grid-col',
            items: '.js-grid-article'
        });
        
        // Ajax
        const current_post_type = grid.dataset.currentPostType;
        const posts_myajax = grid.dataset.postsMyajax;
        let current_page_myajax = grid.dataset.currentPageMyajax;
        const max_page_myajax = grid.dataset.maxPageMyajax;
        const ajax_url = grid.dataset.ajaxUrl;
        const current_action = grid.dataset.action;
    
        var throttleTimer;
        const throttle = (callback, time) => {
            if (throttleTimer) return;
    
            throttleTimer = true;
    
            setTimeout(() => {
                callback();
                throttleTimer = false;
            }, time);
        };
    
        const handleInfiniteScroll = () => {
            throttle(() => {
                const endOfPage = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight;
            
                if (endOfPage) {
                
                    const data = new FormData();
    
                    data.append( 'action', current_action );
                    data.append( 'archive_post_type', current_post_type );
                    data.append( 'query', posts_myajax );
                    data.append( 'page', current_page_myajax );
    
                    fetch(ajax_url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: data
                    })
                    .then((response) => response.text())
                    .then((data) => {
                        if (data) {

                            const posts = $(data);
                            colc.append(posts);

                            current_page_myajax++;
                        }
                    });
    
                }
            
                if (current_page_myajax == max_page_myajax) {
                    removeInfiniteScroll();
                }
    
            }, 1000);
        };
    
        const removeInfiniteScroll = () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleInfiniteScroll);
        };
    
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleInfiniteScroll);
    
    }
```

Thank you.

EDIT

Following the comment of @Barmar I use DOMParser to parse the HTML. The items load while scrolling but not properly. Some of the items are repeated and some others are missing.

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
let posts = doc.querySelectorAll('.js-grid-article')

if (posts) {
    colc.append(posts);
}
```

Comment: You can use `DOMParser` to parse HTML in plain JS. But if `Colcade.append()` expects a jQuery object, I don't see how that helps you.

Comment: @StephenP `$()` does't parse JSON, it parses HTML.

Comment: @Barmar yes it parses the HTML.

Comment: I just checked the Colcade documentation. It looks like you can give vanilla DOM elements to `.append()`. So just use `DOMParser` to parse the HTML returned from the API.

Comment: @Barmar I never use DOMParser until now. I tried to use it after reading your first comment but I don't success to make it work. Do you know how could we apply it in this case? Thanks

Comment: @Barmar I edited the code above with DOMParser. Unfortunately it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Where does `.js-grid-article` come from? You don't have anything like that in the jQuery code. Just try `colc.append(doc)`

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I forget to mention that. This is the class selector that have all the items identified with Colcade. These are the HTML items that I'm trying to parse. If you look at the code where I initialize Colcade (above), you will see I use this class to identify the items.

Comment: I don't see why you need to change that part. So Colcade will continue to apply that filter, you don't need to specify it when you call `.append()`.

Comment: @Barmar How would you write DOMParser() and append() parts? I don't see how to make them work together.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the vanilla JS equivalent of your jQuery code:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const posts = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
colc.append(posts);
```

Comment: thank you. I also tried this equivalent but it produces an error in the console `Unhandled Promise Rejection: HierarchyRequestError: The operation would yield an incorrect node tree`. The error is pointing the colcade js file: This line `fragment.appendChild( elem );`. Finally I don't know if the issue is only related to Colcade or to my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Colcade documentation doesn't seem to be very detailed about this. I'm not sure why it doesn't like this.

Comment: I'm not sure too. Anyway thanks a lot for your help. Thanks to you I discovered `DOMParser` : )